# Para que serve AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Alguém me podia falar, durante o seu percurso de programador, como soube que iria necessitar de aprender a usar AJAX qual era a finalidade etc.?

Estou há horas a tentar perceber AJAX pela W3Schools, mas eu só consigo perceber quando percebo com o que estou a lidar. Tentei sempre tomar outro caminho para não usar AJAX, mas parece-me inevitável continuar sem sabê-lo. E também não consigo simplesmente copiar da Internet copiar para o meu trabalho e funcionar sem saber o que é aquilo e o que vai fazer.

Comment: Aprendi por que queria criar scripts para automatizar algumas ações em sites (isso na época do orkut), mas enfim. Qual a dificuldade? o conceito é simples, você acessa uma URL em "background", sem que o usuário veja, e recebe o conteúdo da página em uma variável. Mais complicado é saber trabalhar com esse conteúdo, caso queira que ele modifique dinamicamente algo na tela, mas, nesse caso, o problema não é o AJAX em si.

Comment: Apenas nesse pequeno comentário consegui 'acessar a portas' no meu raciocinio, e perceber a utilização do AJAX. Obrigado user5978